# Why does graphQL need an endpoint? Can the app be not have everything in itself?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, schema, graphiql

I'm creating an app in react-native and GraphQL.

And following is the code In using for connection to graphql:

```
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: MySessionAwareGraphQLSchema,
  graphiql: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
}));
```

Can we not have everything in the app itself? Why do we need a server/endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `graphqlHTTP` in this example is `express-graphql`, GraphQL doesn't need an endpoint, but `express-graphql` does. Here's the example from [graphql-js](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/).

```js
var { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`);

// The rootValue provides a resolver function for each API endpoint
var rootValue = {
  hello: () => {
    return 'Hello world!';
  },
};

// Run the GraphQL query '{ hello }' and print out the response
graphql({
  schema,
  source: '{ hello }',
  rootValue
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

`schema` here is your schema. `source` is the query you're trying to make. `rootValue` is the resolvers object.

---

Generally speaking, though, GraphQL is *usually* used as an API into your data layer. If you're building an app that doesn't have an external data layer (read "an API"), you may not want to fuss with it.

If you do have an external data layer and you're just not using HTTP, that's fine. GraphQL doesn't require HTTP or any other protocol. That's just the method that most people use.

Comment: Is there another method that could be implemented in app development where I don't have to use any kind of endpoint, on production the things in graphQL can be configured in the app itself, where I do not need any server to host?

Comment: What I'm not able to understand is, in production level I am not wanting to host the graphQL on any server or create an endpoint for it, so in this case will my app work?

Comment: You absolutely can. The code I shared doesn't require any endpoint. You can just call `graphql()` and pass in your schema, query, and resolvers.